# How to update order of entities in NGRX? angular 9

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I am building an application, where I have N columns (N lists of items) and by using a *drag & drop* from angular material I am able to move items between them. I am also using *NGRX* and *EntityAdapter* in my app.

I would like to ask, how can I properly update the order of items when I am moving a object?

Example:
Moving first item from  the "To do" column. that item should be put between *brush teeth* and *pick up groceries*.

[image]

Right now I know how to update column of every item of my list. The thing that I do not know is how to put it in the correct order (sorting is by default, so probably by id).

Item interface:

```js
export interface Item {
  id:string;
  title:string;
  columnId:string;
}
```

Dispatching action for `columnId` update :

```js
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  const droppedItem: SavedJob = event.item.data;
  const previousColumn = event.previousContainer.id;
  const currentColumn = event.container.id;
  this.store.dispatch(
    updateColumn({
      updates: {
        id: droppedItem.id,
        changes: {
          columnId: currentColumn
        }
      }
    })
);
```

Reducer:

```js
on(SavedJobsActions.updateColumn,(state,action)=> {
  return savedJobsAdapter.updateOne(action.updates, {
    ...state,
    entities: {
      ...state.entities,
      [action.updates.id]: {
        ...state.entities[action.updates.id]
      }
    }
  })
})
```

How should I properly update both `columnId` and the order of each item ? I know I should add order key for each Item, but then updating the order value for each column might be hard.

Comment: The [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter) have a bit about adding a `sortComparer`. Perhaps that would have some value to you.

Comment: Hello I know sortComparer, but I am wondering how to update the rest of values ? Each item in each column got order :1,2,3 etz. and how to handle that order update?

Comment: Resolved using Drag and Drop module and functions `moveItemInArray` and `transferArrayItem`
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api

Answer (score 0):

See https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter:
*sortComparer: A compare function used to sort the collection. The comparer function is only needed if the collection needs to be sorted before being displayed. Set to false to leave the collection unsorted, which is more performant during CRUD operations.*

So if you insert a new value, your whole Dictionary should be sorted if you provider a sortComparer. Otherwise it defaults to ID I believe. Implementation of the Comparer depends on how you want to sort, but it should somewhat look like this (assuming columnId is never null).

```
createEntityAdapter({
   sortComparer: (item1: Item, item2: Item) => item1.columnId.localeCompare(item2.columnId),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation.
My workaround is that I put a new attribute called `index`.

For example

```
interface Listing {
 name: string;
 index: number;
}
```

Then, each time the UI sorting happened, let's change the index as well.
In the other words, the selector result will be changed by position.
Then you can get the sorting result.

you still need to use `"sortComparer"` to get the sorting result,
but don't use `id` for sorting, because what we updated is not the ID, it's `index`.

You can check this [index sorting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sort-by-index-of-an-array-in-javascript) technique as well.